# Express js controller to get data from an api service and render the view

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I have this system

1. An API system which only response with JSON objects.
   Example: http://example.com/user/13
     response: {name:'Aesome 1', age: '13'}
2. ExpressJS web app which creates the views and sends the views to the user.

Now what I need to do it to get the JSON object from the API and render a view in ExpressJS and then send to the client.

**So I need to connect the ExpressJS app with this api system.**

Please let me know how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module for making api requests.

In your controller, do like this:

```
var request = require('request');

function(req, res) {
    request.get('http://example.com/user/13', function(err, response, body) {
        if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var locals = JSON.parse(body);
            res.render('<YOUR TEMPLATE>', locals);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: If you really want to access api from server then use the sample, else you can fetch the result using ajax with less overhead of another server to server http call.